# Fixing Black tooltip background in windows 10 under Minimize/Maximize/Close

Tags: windows, background, tooltip

There is a black background on tooltips. It occurs only on title bar Minimize/Maximize/Close option.
I have been facing this for over 2 years now without a solution.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to disable "Fade or slide ToolTips into view" to fix this issue in Windows 10.

Start -> System -> Display -> Advanced System Settings -> Settings (Under Performance) -> Custom -> Uncheck "Fade or slide ToolTips into view"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Settings -> System -> About -> Advanced System Settings -> ...

Comment: This is more of a workaround than an actual solution.  Does anyone have a real solution?  Tooltips work fine everywhere except for the Minimize/Maximize/Close.